# Ubuntu 20.04 laptop doesn't suspend

Tags: suspend

after the latest update, my laptop no longer suspends, even if I type sudo systemctl suspend in terminal. the screen goes black for a quick sec, and then back to the locked screen

I have tried editing the logind.conf file that is recommended elsewhere.

Comment: have the same problem pm-utils seems to make suspend possible, but I also get some kind of frozen UI with only mouse being usable.

Comment: Same problem in 21.10

Answer (score 0):

I strugled several hours with this. At the end I found out my Lenovo T15 had an issue with the Nvidia drivers, I disabled them by following this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/757256/794853