# Ubuntu 20.04 suspend broken

Tags: command-line, 20.04, nvidia, suspend, reboot

I am having the following issue with my laptop. I assume it's Ubuntu related.

When I suspend the laptop (either with `sudo systemctl suspend`, using the shortcut Fn+F4 or from the top right bar, it doesn't matter), the screen goes dark for several seconds, then comes back to the screen which prompts to enter the password as if I just started the laptop. After inputting the correct password, it loads the desktop for a couple of seconds with all the applications closed. After showing the desktop for a couple of seconds, the system locks the laptop, so I need to input the password again.
It seems to me that instead of suspending the system, it is instead first rebooted and then locked.

In addition, I noticed that along with this newly appeared problem commands like `reboot` and `shutdown` stopped working properly. They work only when running with `sudo`, which wasn't the case previously.

I didn't make any changes to the system files recently, except for following the accepted answer in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker), but I doubt that it could've affected the OS this much...

I also found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1289963/ubuntu-20-04-laptop-doesnt-suspend), but I am reluctant to follow it for 2 reasons:

1. Using Nvidia drivers is the core of my work, so I can't disable them
2. It used to be fine before, and the commands got broken a couple of days ago after more than a year of normal work

Could it be because of an Nvidia-driver-unrelated issue? Any thoughts?

Comment: it has driven me nuts for 4 years...  pmutils has pm-suspend which works for me, though lately (it is mercurial) I had to kill nordvpn process for it to work. you can also edit sudoers with visudo to allow for pm-suspend (or whatever) to work without password prompt. my keyboard shortcut to suspend is then 'sudo pm-suspend". most likely a lack of support from AMD (or HP in my case). I have the latest BIOS.